# Did 謠's phonetic component (䍃) semantically shift it away from 言?

Tags: etymology

You can spot that (the left-hand side of) [謠](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%AC%A0#Chinese) originates from [言](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A8%80#Chinese). I screenshot [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E8%AC%A0#).

1. Did the phonetic component 䍃 spawn, or have anything to do with, the [semantic narrowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change#Typology_by_Blank_(1999)) from  言 to 謠?
2. If not, what beget 謠's  songful (#1, 2 below) and defamatory (#3) meanings that are more specific than 言?
3. For example, consider [謠言](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%AC%A0%E8%A8%80#Chinese). Couldn't 謠言 have been originally compounded as 言謠?

> **謠**
>
> 1. (alt. form [䚻](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%9A%BB#Chinese), [繇](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%B9%87#Chinese), [猶](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%8C%B6#Chinese)‡) to [sing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sing) without [instruments](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/instrument)
> 2. (alt. form [䚻](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%9A%BB#Chinese), [繇](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%B9%87#Chinese)) [folk song](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/folk_song); [ballad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ballad)
> 3. [fake](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fake) [circulating](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circulating) [words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/word); [fake](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fake) [rumour](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rumour)

[image]

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. The word represented by the character 謠 does not originate from the word represented by the character 言 (characters are not words, they are representations of words). Semantic narrowing only applies to one word (e.g. from the Wikipedia link, mouse *rodent* narrowing to mouse *computer device*), while 謠 and 言 are different words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Did the phonetic component 䍃 spawn, or have anything to do with, the semantic narrowing from 言 to 謠?

"䍃" is a common 声旁, 谣 is a pictophonetic character (形声字), its   pronunciation is from 䍃, 摇, 遥, 鹞 are pictophonetic characters from 䍃 too.

> If not, what beget 謠's songful (#1, 2 below) and defamatory (#3) meanings that are more specific than 言?

What's 歌谣? Some **words** with tunes. What's 谣言? Fabricated **words** without facts. What's 言? **Words**. 言 is the meaningful part of pictophonetic character 谣.

> For example, consider 謠言. Couldn't 謠言 have been originally compounded as 言謠?

"谣" is the "adjective" of "言". What type of words"言"? Uncertain or suspicious words. If it's 言谣, "言" and "谣" should be parallel.

---

Actually, I can't understand your exactly question because in fact, your question can be clearer.